# Woher kommt die „goldene Ananas“?

Tags: etymology, idiom

„Die Goldene Ananas ist als umgangssprachliche Redewendung ein fiktiver Preis, der für einen Wettbewerb mit eigentlich irrelevantem Ausgang vergeben wird“ … und sie hat sogar einen [eigenen Wikipedia-Artikel](http://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Goldene_Ananas&stableid=132020284) (Quelle des Zitats).

Leider gibt es dort ebenso wenig wie im Duden eine Erklärung zur Herkunft und Google liefert auch nicht viel (Redewendungsseiten ohne Herkunftserklärung, offensichtlich ausgedachte Foren-Antworten).

Also warum „Ananas“ für etwas, dessen Resultat eigentlich Banane ist? ;-)

Comment: Vielleicht hilft es weiter, wenn wir wissen wer den Begriff populär gemacht hat. Ewigkeiten wird das nicht her sein, ich schätze um die 20 Jahre.

Comment: Hier ein paar Quellenhinweise: http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/cgi-portal/de/wort_www?site=22&Wort_id=18207780&bl=208

Comment: +1 für den letzten Satz.

Answer (score 6):

Die [Thüringer Allgemeine](http://www.thueringer-allgemeine.de/web/zgt/fussball-wm/detail/-/specific/Deutschland-oder-Uruguay-Das-Spiel-um-die-goldene-Ananas-194322923) schrieb 2010 in einer Glosse:

> ...die Ananas, von der es über 2000 Arten gibt, stammt aus Südamerika. Wie auch die Redensart von der "goldenen": Verarmte Plantagen-Arbeiter prägten sie. Sie fanden ihren Verdienst im Gegensatz zum vertreibenden Großabnehmer so klein bis winzig, dass ihnen für die Mühe und Strapazen bei Aufzucht und Ernte lediglich die sprichwörtliche "goldene Ananas" blieb.

Jemand mit Kenntnissen in Spanisch möge das bitte versuchen zu bekräftigen.

Comment: Vielleicht mag c.p. uns ja mal erzählen, was er unter dem Stichwort "La Piña De Oro" findet...

Comment: Das deckt sich mit der [Foren-Antwort](http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/woher-kommt-der-ausdruck-goldene-ananas), die ich mangels Quellen und Zusammenhang für ausgedacht hielt. Erklärt leider nicht, was "golden" an der Ananas ist, warum sie für den Gewinner eines (irrelevanten) Wettbewerbs da sein muss (statt für alle Beteiligten) und warum "piña de oro" oder "piña dorada" bzw. "golden pineapple" nichts in diesem Sinne zu bedeuten scheinen.

Comment: @arne.b da du hier von "golden pineapple" sprichst... laut [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=die+goldene+ananas) ist die richtige Übersetzung "dead rubber", hilft (mir zumindest) aber leider nicht weiter, um die Herkunft des deutschen Ausdrucks zu verstehen.

Comment: @arne.b *Erklärt leider nicht, was "golden" an der Ananas ist* - schon mal eine aufgeschnitten? :-)

Comment: Viele Preise sind "golden", z.B. die goldene Kamera, die goldene Palme, der goldene Bär, der Golden Globe, der goldene Zuckerhut oder auch als Negativpreise die goldene Himbeere oder der goldene Windbeutel. Insofern ist es durchaus naheliegend, auch für einen fiktiven Preis den Zusatz "golden" zu verwenden.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Vll. um einen stärkeren Kontrast zu der Bedeutungslosigkeit des Preises zu schaffen.